# angular: LOCATION_INITIALIZED what is it and why use it?

Tags: angular

I stumbled upon `LOCATION_INITIALIZED` when researching loading ngx-translate translations in `APP_INITIALIZER` (see [enter link description here](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/517#issuecomment-299637956)

```
import { Injector, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { LOCATION_INITIALIZED } from '@angular/common';

export function appInitializerFactory(translate: TranslateService, injector: Injector) {
  return () => new Promise<any>((resolve: any) => {
    const locationInitialized = injector.get(LOCATION_INITIALIZED, Promise.resolve(null));
    locationInitialized.then(() => {
      const langToSet = 'en-GB'
      translate.setDefaultLang('en-US');
      translate.use(langToSet).subscribe(() => {
        console.info(`Successfully initialized '${langToSet}' language.'`);
      }, err => {
        console.error(`Problem with '${langToSet}' language initialization.'`);
      }, () => {
        resolve(null);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

According to [angular's source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c8a1a14b87e5907458e8e87021e47f9796cb3257/packages/platform-browser/src/browser/location/browser_platform_location.ts) it's when, in my case, the browser (platform) is ready (DOM, Location and History is ready, would be my guess).

Unfortunately it's not really documented anywhere.

I used the example above without `LOCATION_INITIALIZED` and it worked as expected.

So why should I care about `LOCATION_INITIALIZED` and when should I use it?

Answer (score 1):

I used the same code to initialize safely the *ngx-translate* translations in order to use *instant* method of the Translate service and I had the same doubt.

Anyway, searching online and according to the documentation for the [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) we just need to provide our function(s) that will be executed during app init (using a promise initialization does not complete until the Promise is resolved).

So yes, you can get rid of the LOCATION_INITIALIZED and use this function for instance ( I am using it and it is working fine).

```
export function appInitializerTranslationsFactory(translate: TranslateService) {
return () => new Promise<any>((resolve: any) => {
        const langToSet = 'en';
        translate.setDefaultLang('en');
        translate.use(langToSet).subscribe(() => {}, err => {}, () => {
            resolve(null);
        });
});
```

}